# insert special character or other language character as it is in SQL server using python

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlite, character-encoding, pyodbc

This is my code to insert record into sql server:

```
 row = { 'CompanyName': 'OPAP Group',
         'Location': 'Αθήνα',
         'JobPosted': '5 ημέρες πριν',
      }


cur.execute("insert into table1(CompanyName, Location,JobPosted) values(?,?,?)", (               
              row['CompanyName'], row['Location'], row['JobPosted']))

 cur.commit()
```

But when i execute, I get the incorrect output in SQL Server table as below for 'Location' and 'JobPosted':

```
       { 'CompanyName': 'OPAP Group',
         'Location': '????a',
         'JobPosted': '5 ?µ??e? p???',
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set charset to utf8mb4 while connecting to database like below:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(
                    host="127.0.0.1",
                    user="root",
                    passwd="",
                    db="db_name",
                    charset='utf8mb4',
                    use_unicode=True
                    )
```